# How to set vertical length of a column in a multicols environment avoid column breaking

Tags: multicol

The first column break in two parts. How can avoid it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 %Some packages I commonly use.
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage{enumerate}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[top=1 in,bottom=1in, left=1 in, right=1 in]{geometry}

\usepackage{libertine}
  \usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}


 \begin{multicols}{3}
POSCAR\\ 
fcc (100)\\
 surface\\
 3.53\\
  .50000   .50000   .00000\\
 -.50000   .50000   .00000\\
 .00000   .00000  5.00000\\
 5\\
 Selective Dynamics\\
Kartesisch\\
   .00000   .00000   .00000 F F F\\
  .00000   .50000   .50000 F F F\\
  .00000   .00000  1.00000 F F F\\
  .00000   .50000  1.50000 T T T\\
 .00000   .00000  2.00000 T T T\\

 INCAR
 ISTART = 0; ICHARG = 2\\
 general:\\
  SYSTEM = clean Ni(100) surface\\
  ENCUT = 270 \\
  ISMEAR = 2 ; SIGMA = 0.2\\
  ALGO = Fast\\
  EDIFF = 1E-6\\
  spin:\\
  ISPIN=2\\
  MAGMOM = 5*1\\
dynamic:
NSW = 100\\
 POTIM = 0.8
 IBRION = 1

KPOINTS
k-points\\

0\ Monkhorst-Pack\ 9 9 1\ 0 0 0\

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have some doubts that multicol is the right environment for whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: which one should I use?

Comment: the column breaking is the least of the problems, it is very hard to guess what output you want but presumably you don't want it to look like the image? For example aren't the sections like `Kartesisch\\    .00000   .00000   .00000 F F F\\
  .00000   .50000   .50000 F F F\\   .00000   .00000  1.00000 F F F\\   .00000   .50000  1.50000 T T T\\  .00000   .00000  2.00000 T T T\\ `  supposed to be lined up as a 6-column table, you are just setting them as word spaced lines with no alignment at all????

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the text is some kind of config file display? I set here as verbatim but force a column break using `\columnbreak` at a hopefully good place rather than latex just break the text at the half way point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 %Some packages I commonly use.
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage{enumerate}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[top=1 in,bottom=1in, left=1 in, right=1 in]{geometry}

\usepackage{libertine}
  \usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}

\setlength\columnseprule{1pt}

 \begin{multicols}{2}\small

\begin{verbatim}
POSCAR 
fcc (100)
 surface
 3.53
  .50000   .50000   .00000
 -.50000   .50000   .00000
  .00000   .00000  5.00000
 5
 Selective Dynamics
Kartesisch
  .00000   .00000   .00000 F F F
  .00000   .50000   .50000 F F F
  .00000   .00000  1.00000 F F F
  .00000   .50000  1.50000 T T T
  .00000   .00000  2.00000 T T T
\end{verbatim}
\columnbreak
\begin{verbatim}
 INCAR
 ISTART = 0; ICHARG = 2
 general:
  SYSTEM = clean Ni(100) surface
  ENCUT = 270 
  ISMEAR = 2 ; SIGMA = 0.2
  ALGO = Fast
  EDIFF = 1E-6
  spin:
  ISPIN=2
  MAGMOM = 5*1
dynamic:
NSW = 100
 POTIM = 0.8
 IBRION = 1

KPOINTS
k-points

0 Monkhorst-Pack 9 9 1 0 0 0
\end{verbatim}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```